# Using Multiple Switch gives Blanc Compponent in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-router

i have been trying to link some component together and load some differently.
These Component are in different files and folder but the structure are similar

---

```
<Link to="/home">Home</Link>
   <Link to="/signin">Signin</Link>

   <Switch>
   <Route path="/home" exact component={Home} />
   <Route path="/signin" exact component={SignIn} />
</Switch>
```

### App.js

---

```
<h4>This is Home Page</h4>
   <Link to="/about" >About</Link>
   <Link to="/contact">Contact</Link>

   <Switch>
  {/* <Route path={match.url} exact={true} component={HomeDefaultComponent} /> */}
  <Route exact path={match.url + '/about'} component={About} />
  <Route exact path="/contact" component={Contact} />
</Switch>
```

### Home.js

---

```
<h4>Sign In</h4>
    <Link to="/negative">Negative</Link>
    <Link to="/positive">Positive</Link>
    <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/negative" component={Negative} />
    <Route exact path="/positive" component={Positive} />
</Switch>
```

### SignIn.js

---

Anytime i click on the "/about" path i get an empty page showing no info.
And all Components are different file but there are subcomponents too just to update...

Comment: Only the `about` button not working well? (Why you use `match.url`?)... In general, it is better to use the `Switch` one (Sound "buggy" to work like your code idea). "Hello World" example: https://codesandbox.io/s/vvoqvk78?file=/components/Main.js (In this example `switch` declare under `main.js`).

Comment: I think i have tried but returning the same error